# Parsing html using xpath in Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse some html code (carthtml) in Python2.7 and Flask0.12. There are 3 different items in 'carthtml'. I tried to get all of these items into 'items' in 'def getCart()' using xpath.

I want to print the name of each item one by one, so I used a for-loop

```
for idx, item in enumerate(items):
    product_name = get_value_by_xpath(item,
                                    '//div[@class="product-name"]/a/text()')
    print product_name
```

The expected output is:

```
Piqué Polo Romper
Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit
OshKosh Mary Jane Sneakers
```

but my actual output is:

```
Piqué Polo Romper
Piqué Polo Romper
Piqué Polo Romper
```

I guess in the for-loop, 'item' doesn't take 1 item, but rather all 3 items at each repeat. Any help would be very appreciated.

Here's my code

app.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from datetime import datetime
import traceback
import requests
import sys
import logging.handlers


reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def getCart():    
    html_tree = parse_htmlpage(carthtml)
    items = get_elements_by_xpath(html_tree, '//div[@class="primary-content"]//div[@class="mini-cart-product clearfix"]')
    product_list = []
    if items is False or items is None:
        #logger.debug("[T/F:T, e_id:" + str(e_id) + ", API_URL:/add_to_cart, Msg:No data from CARTERS]")
        return jsonify({'result_code': 0})
    if len(items) > 0:
        for idx, item in enumerate(items):
            product_name = get_value_by_xpath(item,
                                           '//div[@class="product-name"]/a/text()')
            print product_name

    return


def parse_htmlpage(html_src):
    detail_html = html.fromstring(html_src)
    page_tree = etree.ElementTree(detail_html)

    return page_tree

def get_elements_by_xpath(page_tree, target_xpath):
    target_value_list = page_tree.xpath(target_xpath)
    return target_value_list

def get_value_by_xpath(page_tree, target_xpath):
    target_value = page_tree.xpath(target_xpath)
    return target_value
```

carthtml

```
<div class="primary-content">
<div class="mini-cart-product clearfix">
    <div class="mini-cart-image">
        <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795039832.html"><img src="https://www.carters.com/dw/image/v2/AAMK_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-carters_master_catalog/default/dw182a85c8/hi-res/118H023_Default.jpg?sw=470" alt="Piqué Polo Romper" title="Piqué Polo Romper"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart-attributes">
        <div class="product-name">
            <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795039832.html">Piqué Polo Romper</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="mini-cart-product clearfix">
    <div class="mini-cart-image">
        <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795419986.html"><img src="https://www.carters.com/dw/image/v2/AAMK_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-carters_master_catalog/default/dw540ec9a5/hi-res/127G525_Default.jpg?sw=470" alt="Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit" title="Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit"></a>
    </div>


    <div class="mini-cart-attributes">
        <div class="product-name">
            <a href="/carters-baby-boy-one-pieces/190795419986.html">Neon Little Brother Jumpsuit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="mini-cart-product clearfix">

    <div class="mini-cart-image">
        <a href="/oshkosh-baby-girl-shoes-casual-shoes/888737142503.html"><img src="https://www.carters.com/dw/image/v2/AAMK_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-carters_master_catalog/default/dw32891bda/hi-res/OF150011_Navy.jpg?sw=470" alt="OshKosh Mary Jane Sneakers" title="OshKosh Mary Jane Sneakers"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart-attributes">

        <div class="product-name">
            <a href="/on/demandware.store/Sites-Carters-Site/default/RedirectURL-CookieMigration?url=https%3a%2f%2fwww%2ecarters%2ecom%2fs%2fSites-Carters-Site%2fdw%2fshared_session_redirect%3furl%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww%2eoshkosh%2ecom%252Foshkosh-baby-girl-shoes-casual-shoes%252F888737142503%2ehtml%253Fsrd%253Dtrue">OshKosh Mary Jane Sneakers</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could it be the missing `return target_value` ?

Comment: @corn3lius Oh it's just my mistake. I added it. Thanks :) but it's not the problem.

Comment: try `product_name = get_value_by_xpath(item, './/div[@class="product-name"]/a/text()')`. Also note that your condition `if items is False or items is None` will never return True as empty or not empty `list` cannot be `None` or `False`!

Comment: @Andersson Thank you very much. It was xpath problem. I edited it form '//div[@class ...' to './/div[@class...', and fixed it :)